# Qual è il significato dell'espressione "a scapito di" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto questa frase, che fa parte di una lettera:

> Non siamo certo davanti – questo Lei lo sa bene – a un individuo raccomandabile; quanto, pare certo, a un personaggio privo di saldi princìpi e incline a certi raggiri – prevalentemente diretti **a scapito di** signore – che hanno sempre come scopo ultimo il danaro.

Ho cercato il [significato dell'espressione "a scapito di" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/scapito/) ed ecco quello che ho trovato:

> frequente la locuz. *a scapito di*, con grave pregiudizio e danno: *la diminuzione dei costi non deve essere a s. della qualità della produzione*.

Tuttavia, non capisco bene il senso di questa espressione nel brano precedente. Significa che gli atti del personaggio descritto nel testo facevano diminuire la sua reputazione come "signore"?

Comment: Delle volte, se non capisci bene il senso, è utile consultare il dizionario anche per le altre parole che più o meno già conosci. In questo caso probabilmente è la mancanza del corretto significato di "signore" che ti lascia confusa.

Comment: Forse hai ragione, @ErikvanDoren, ma in questo caso sapevo già che "signore" è anche il plurale di "signora". Quando vado in Italia, sempre spiego a mio marito che, si vede la scritta "signore" nella porta di un bagno pubblico, si riferisce al plurale di "signora" e quindi lui non deve entrare.

Comment: Io credo che *a scapito di* si possa utilizzare come forma con accezione negativa di *verso* o *a favore di*. Ad esempio, si potrebbe dire che una persona *ha sempre delle attenzioni verso i suoi colleghi*, ed un'altra *mette in giro pettegolezzi a scapito della direzione*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, qui “signore” è femminile plurale. Il tale di cui si parla, evidentemente, è un truffatore ed è solito prendere in giro le donne a fini di lucro.

Comment: GIusto. Mi suona malissimo quel “diretti”.

Answer (score 4):

Anche lo Zingarelli ne dà una definizione simile, forse non proprio chiarissima.

> ***a scapito di***, con pregiudizio, danno: *agisce così a scapito della nostra amicizia*

Dunque *a scapito di signore* ha più o meno lo stesso significato di *a danno di signore*, qui nel senso dell'inglese *at the expenses of*...

Altre volte sento usare *a scapito di* anche nel senso di *nonostante*, per esempio "A scapito del fatto di essere semplicemente bambini..."

È possibile che la locuzione venga usata con altri significati, ma questi mi sembrano senz'altro i più comuni.